# Blending div's background

Tags: html, css, background, photoshop, color-blending

I want such background blending effect like in screenshot attached. 
I have already used rgba backgrounds but that does not looks like my designs.

Here is the image and code I used.

I tried using different background image and css3 elements but its not working properly.

Is this possible to this using any jquery?

[image]

```
.green_band {background: rgba(24, 95, 14, 0.5);}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, at this time (summer 2014) you can only fake that using alpha transparency (e.g. using `rgba`).

The CSS blend modes will come, but “it is an upcoming technology, and, at the time of this writing, browser support is patchy”.

See [“Getting to know CSS Blend Modes”](http://dev.opera.com/articles/getting-to-know-css-blend-modes/) for an introduction and [the browser support tables for `background-blend-mode`](http://caniuse.com/css-backgroundblendmode).

Using the upcoming CSS blend-mode properties:

```
background-color: rgb(24, 95, 14);
background-blend-mode: multiply;
```

Here is the [W3C Editor’s Draft: Compositing and Blending Level 1](http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/compositing-1/)

Comment: @vico Well, that is a technology for 2015…

Comment: that won't come into play in another 2 -3 year since people don't like to update stuff

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a way to use blending modes outside of Photoshop unless you want to write WebGL shaders.